# Process: 17925 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm trying to Restart Apache in AWS linux 2 (EC2 server).

When I run `sudo systemctl restart httpd` I get this issue

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
> for details.

And when I run `systemctl status httpd.service` I get

> httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
> (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset
> : disabled)   Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
> └─php-fpm.conf    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-01-14 10:13:55 UTC; 12s ago
> Docs: man:httpd.service(8)   Process: 17925 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, s
> tatus=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 17925 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Status: "Reading configuration..."

This happened when I try to add [Configure SSL/TLS on Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html?fbclid=IwAR0t9X9WH6b6Kvbg8iF_54OEWKr_Y1dJbvXw5eKHl7TJoif82TKy73STe78).

And I did commented this line in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out an answer by my self,

in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file it's created a line like,

```
SLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

We need to change **SLCertificateFile** to **SSLCertificateFile**

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

Then run

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```